# Pagination in jsp using jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jquery-pagination

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    var items = $("table tr"); 
    var numItems = items.length; 
    var perPage = 2; 
    items.slice(perPage).hide(); 
    $(".pagination-page").pagination({ 
        items: numItems, 
        itemsOnPage: perPage, 
        cssStyle: "light-theme", 
        onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { 
            var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
            var showTo = showFrom + perPage; 
            items.hide(); 
           .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Edit your question instead of adding codes in your comment... and **format your codes**

Comment: Even though it is not formatted, this piece of code looks strange: .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();

Comment: I have copied this code from stackoverflow only for pagination

Comment: please help me how to do pagination .I am new to jquery I dont have idea how to use jquery so explain me how to use jquery please anyone....

Comment: What kind of pagination you need? You can make ajax (or any other kind) call for new pages, or hide some pages and show ones you need

Comment: How could we do the pagination using ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of syntax errors in your example. Assuming that your html table is populated correctly on the server-side, this seems to work fine:

```js
$(function($) {
  var items = $("table tr");
  var numItems = items.length;
  var perPage = 2;
  items.slice(perPage).hide();
  $(".pagination-page").pagination({
    items: numItems,
    itemsOnPage: perPage,
    cssStyle: "light-theme",
    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
      var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
      var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
      items.hide();
      items.slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ciiing-project-learn.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1792/trunk/projects/eddie/app/webroot/js/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9</td></tr>
  <tr><td>10</td></tr>
</table>

<div class="pagination-page"></div>
```

Comment: the function need to be saved as jquery.min.js??

Comment: $(function($) { is having number of syntax errors you said,then how come its working fine in your example

Comment: if table have id=something, then instead of var items = $("table tr"); can i use var items = $(".something");??

Comment: No, the names of the Javascript import files don't matter. It is the contents that matter. Also, if you have id="something", then your selector should be $("#something"). If you have class="something", then your selector should be $(".something");

Comment: but the above code is not  working in my case I have included the script lines in head tag and created jquery.min.js page. In that i copied above function it should work properly .Why it is not working??

Comment: It has to be something specific to your HTML page. Can you examine the Javascript console output in Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools, and check what errors you get? Post your generated HTML source.

Comment: i have imported above two src of jquery. In jquery.simplePagination.js last line })(jQuery); in this jQuery is not defined( error) occured