# How to display rows fetched from a database in multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I currently have a JSP code that displays all the records from a database. I want to split it into pages, say 10 rows per page. I tried the solution I found in this post using bootstrap and datatables, but I still get all rows on one page.

This is the code that I tried.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
.
.
.
.
.
.

<table BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0 WIDTH=90% id="table1" class="display">
        <thead>
            <td><b>FGC ID</b></td> 
            <td><b>PERSON</b></td>           
            <td><b>TYPE OF EXPERIMENT</b></td>           
            <td><b>FACTOR</b></td>
            <td><b>TISSUE</b></td> 
            <td><b>CONDITIONS</b></td>           
            <td><b>SAMPLE ID</b></td>           
            <td><b>SAMPLE NAME</b></td> 
            <td><b>DATE</b></td> 
            <td><b>COMMENTS</b></td>           
            <td><b>BROSWER TRACK</b></td>           
            <td><b>BROSWER TRACK</b></td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
  <c:forEach items="${experimentList}" var="experimentList">    
        <tr>
            <td>${experimentList.FGCID}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.person}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.type}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.factor}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.tissue}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.condition}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.sample}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.name}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.date}</td>
            <td>${experimentList.comments}</td>
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getfiles" method="post">  
            <td><input type="submit" name="track_1" value="positive" /><input type="hidden" name="track1" value="${experimentList.track1}" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="track_2" value="negative" /><input type="hidden" name="track2" value="${experimentList.track2}" /></td>
    </form> 


</tr> 
  </c:forEach> 

    </tbody>


</table>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- DATA TABES SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</center>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    $("#table1").dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100,  -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]]
       });
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a lazy loading solution or a solution thats loads everything at once and then sorts it into pages?

Comment: Something that loads everything at once and sorts it into pages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination in jsp using jQuery is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577116/pagination-in-jsp-using-jquery-is-not-working)

Comment: Why not just load that data into a JSON string and feed it into the dataTable's "data" property and let dataTable handle all that for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would just pass the data down to the view as an AJAX string and load it like this:

```
    $("#table1").dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100,  -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        "data" : ${model.experimentJSON},
        "serverside" : false,
        "paginate": true,
       });
   });
```

Note that this isn't responsive to changes on the server, but neither is your example. If you want it to be responsive, you will need to use the ajax property like:

```
    $("#table1").dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100,  -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]]
        "ajax": {
            url: "serverAction",
            type: "POST",
            data: function(d) {
                return {json: JSON.stringift(d)};
            }
        },
        "serverSide:" true,
        "paginate": true
       });
   });
```

Then you can just let the dataTable options handle the rest.

Comment: Hi Sinistralis, Thank you for your response. I am still having trouble in displaying 10 records per page, using the 1st method of viewing the data as an AJAX string. My data is in the form of an ArrayList, and I am using requestDispatcher on the server side to fetch it in JSP.

Comment: Pagination should be handled automatically. (I would recommend taking out iDisplayLength and aLengthMenu as these are legacy and deprecated). It's possible those commands are making this more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the code from [this](http://dotnetcluster.blogspot.com/2011/07/paging-in-html-table-using-javascript.html) example for client side pagination with tables.

Answer (score 0):

This can be even simpler as what you want to do. Just add the displaytag jar and the below link will helo you doing the pagination on the resultset you are getting from the database.

Its easy and simple and dont have to work on javascript for doing it. Also its Client side, so you are good on that part.

[Display Tag Library](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-pagination-example-1.html)